# Junit test fails when I use try and catch block. Why?

Tags: java, junit, try-catch, throw

I want to test my java code using Junit test framework. In my source code I use try and catch block to handle exceptions. In my test method I want to test this method. If my source code return some exceptions and if it matches in my test method, My test will pass otherwise fail. But my code does not pass this test.

I found a way to figure it out but I want to use try and catch block. Also I will share it.

**NOT WORKING**
**My Source Code(I want to test this method)**

```
    public boolean isCreateAccount(String amount) {
    
    try { 
        
        Double balance = Double.parseDouble(amount);
        
        if(balance < 0)
             throw new Exception();

    
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        System.out.println("WARNING: Invalid amount!");
    } 
    
         return false;
    
    }
```

**This is my test method in JUnit**

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException expectedException = ExpectedException.none();

@Test
public void testCreateAccountInvalidAmount() {

    expectedException.expect(Exception.class);
    accountServices.isCreateAccount("-100");    
    
}
```

**WORKING**
**This way is working but I want to use try and catch block**
**My Source Code(I want to test this method)**

```
    public void isCreateCheckingAccount(String amount) {
            
        Double balance = Double.parseDouble(amount); 

        if(balance < 0)
             throw new Exception();

    
     }
```

**This is my test method in JUnit**

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException expectedException = ExpectedException.none();

@Test
public void testCreateAccountInvalidAmount() {

    expectedException.expect(Exception.class);
    accountServices.isCreateAccount("-100");    
    
}
```

Comment: You're saying to expect the test to throw an exception. Does your test method throw an exception?

Comment: Looks like the surrounding try catch block is catching the exception, stopping any exceptions from being thrown

Comment: @macedonboy –  I totally agree with you. I do not have enough experience about Junit. In my isCreateAccount method, I create exception and catch it because of that my test method does not get it. I am not sure how to figure it out using try and catch. Maybe there is no solution.

Comment: You could alway re-throw the exception if you insist on doing it that way, but you could also change the if statement to print the message, then throw the exception

Comment: @Savior - No, Let's say you created a method in your mainDriver. This method throws an exception. I want to test this expection in my Test method using Junit.

Comment: No code (let alone a test) can "look into" what a method is doing (to detect that something within that execution stack threw an exception). All you have to work with is the output of that method, either the return value or whether it returned normally or because of an exception.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out this problem. Thank you for your help guys. I share my solution here. I hope it helps if you have this kind of problem.

// this code in my service layer...

```
@Override
public boolean isCreateAccount(String amount) {
    
    try { 
            
        isValidAmount(amount);
        double balance = Double.parseDouble(amount);    
        createAccount(balance);
        return true;
        
    } catch(NullPointerException e) {
        log.warn("WARNING: Empty Amount!");
        System.out.println("\nWARNING: Empty Amount!");
        
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) { 
        log.warn("WARNING: Invalid amount!");
        System.out.println("\nWARNING: Invalid amount!");
        
    } catch (NegativeAmountException e) {
        log.warn("WARNING: Amount must have a positive number!");       
        System.out.println("\nWARNING: Amount must have a positive number!");
        
    } catch (InsufficientAmountException e) {
        log.warn("WARNING: Not enough money to open a checking account!");
        System.out.println("\nWARNING: Not enough money to open a checking 
    account!");
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

// this code in my service layer...

```
@Override
public void isValidAmount(String money) {
    
    if(money == null || money.length() == 0) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Empty Amount");
    }
    
    double amount = 0.0D;
    
    try {
        amount = Double.parseDouble(money);         
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new NumberFormatException("Invalid Amount");
    } 
        
    if(amount < 0.0D) {
        throw new NegativeAmountException("Negative Amount");
    }       
    
    if(amount < 25.0D) {
        throw new InsufficientAmountException("Insufficient Amount");
    }

}
```

//This code in my Test Class in Junit

```
@Test
public void testCreateCheckingAccountNullAmount() {
    expectedException.expect(NullPointerException.class);
    expectedException.expectMessage("Empty Amount");
    accountServices.isValidAmount("");              
}

@Test
public void testCreateCheckingAccountInvalidAmount() {
    
    expectedException.expect(NumberFormatException.class);
    expectedException.expectMessage("Invalid Amount");
    accountServices.isValidAmount("a100");          
}

@Test
public void testCreateCheckingAccountNegativeAmount() {
    expectedException.expect(NegativeAmountException.class);
    expectedException.expectMessage("Negative Amount");
    accountServices.isValidAmount("-10");
}

@Test
public void testCreateCheckingAccountInsufficientAmount() {
    expectedException.expect(InsufficientAmountException.class);
    expectedException.expectMessage("Insufficient Amount");
    accountServices.isValidAmount("10");
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't the forum for code reviews, but I'm glad you found a solution that worked for you :-) Good luck with your application. BTW If my solution help, please accept.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your method. It has the following behaviours:

- If amount is negative or not a number, it prints something to sysout (which is bad; you should not mix responsibilities like this; your Account tool is surely not also your UI layer, but that's a secondary issue). Otherwise it prints nothing.
- Then, regardless of what you passed in, it prints false.

So, the observable behaviour of this method is that it returns false, and that it prints something to sysout.

Testing that it returns false is trivial; `assertFalse(services.isCreateAccount("100")` will do it (though, presumably, the fact that your method always returns false is in fact an error).

Testing that it prints something to sysout is complicated. That's because of the fundamental issue that you shouldn't be printing anything there. If output is part of the point, then instead of printing to `System.out`, pass along some output abstraction (perhaps a `java.io.PrintWriter`) to `AccountServices` so that you can pass some variant of that as part of the test; a variant that can be configured to check if some expected output shows up here.

You seem to be under the impression that this method throws something. It doesn't - it **catches** something. In junit, saying: "I expect this exception" means you expect it to fall out of the method, i.e. the opposite: That the method does NOT catch that, or even, that the method explicitly throws that.

Comment: thank you. In my test case, input is "100". I do not test "aaa100" but I understand your approach. I want to test my code in Service Layer and I need try and catch block. I think I write a test method in my test class and using "throw new Exception()" What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want:

```
public boolean isCreateAccount(String amount) throws Exception {

    Double balance = Double.parseDouble(amount);

    if (balance < 0) {
        System.out.println("WARNING: Invalid amount!");
        throw new Exception();
    }

    return false;
}
```

Returning false doesn't make much sense though.

If you really want that try catch block:

```
public boolean isCreateAccount(String amount) throws Exception {

    try {
        Double balance = Double.parseDouble(amount);
        if (balance < 0) {
            System.out.println("WARNING: Invalid amount!");
            throw new Exception();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }

    return false;
}
```

And these basic tests works for both versions:

```
public class AccountTest {

    @Rule
    public ExpectedException expectedException = ExpectedException.none();

    @Test
    public void testCreateAccountInvalidAmount() throws Exception {
        Account accountServices = new Account();
        expectedException.expect(Exception.class);
        accountServices.isCreateAccount("-100");
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreateAccountZeroAmount() throws Exception {
        Account accountServices = new Account();
        assertFalse(accountServices.isCreateAccount("0"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreateAccountValidAmount() throws Exception {
        Account accountServices = new Account();
        assertFalse(accountServices.isCreateAccount("1"));
    }
}
```

Comment: for this part, yes you can use throws, but I need try and catch block in My service Layer. thanks.

Comment: throw e; It did not work. I have another question. My code will return boolean and also it can throw exception. When I test my code to check iscreateaccount depending on returning type(boolean) it works. Maybe Junit waits for only one return type. Exception or boolean ?? Maybe I need to write test method for this isCreateAccount ??

Comment: You cannot have both an Exception and a boolean. It's one or the other and the only boolean isCreateAccount returns is false.

Comment: I think main problem is catch because After I throw an exception, I catch it in my method and handle it.  I will write test method in my test class and I will just throw exception there and then I will compare it with my expectedExpection variable. If someone finds a different way, I will try it. Thank you @macedonboy

Comment: @Isa, What doesn't work?, I've included a version of isCreateAccount and it works as expected

Comment: I will try now. thank you I hope it works. I will let you know.  @ macedonboy

Comment: It worked for test but when I run the my program, it did not work. To be honest I tried your way before. It looks so smart for test part but now my code does not run. It says add everwhere throws exception, I mean whereever I used this methods (interface, service layer, main method etc. )

Comment: That sounds like a different problem. The tests show isCreateAccount works fine for numeric values. If isCreateAccount throws an exception when being used, then show us the code for that and the exception stacktrace. Although it would be better to raise a new question for that.

Comment: I solved this problem such a great way. I will share my solution code. I hope you will like it.